# Magento Autmatically redirect to a template file from another template file

Tags: magento

I have a custom template file. There i am displaying a message. So after 10 second from the page load, i need to redirect to the admin login page automatically. I tried $this->_redirect('');. But that did not work.

Can anyone help me please. Thank You.

Comment: Could you post your code that you have used to try and accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location='<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl().(string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName')?>';
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

Put this script in your file it will works for you

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below will resolve your question. If your site uses jquery, you may just paste this in your template. Otherwise, you need to include jquery in your Magento header.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function() { document.location = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl('adminhtml'); ?>'; }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you're unsure about some presumptions, it's often good to ask about those presumptions in a comment to the original question. That way, the OP is also encouraged to update the question with that info, thus improving the question as a source of knowledge for future readers.